# Split single column to multiple

Tags: sql

My table look like this:

```
id    customer_code   comments
-----------------------------------
1       Dilbert        true
2       Dilbert        false
3       Wally          true
4       wally          true
5       wally          false
```

I need to results look like this:

```
id  customer_code  x1     x2
------------------------------
1   Dilbert        ture
2   Dilbert               false
3   wally          ture
4   wally          ture
5   wally                 false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [id], [customer_code],
CASE [comments] WHEN 'TRUE' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE NULL END AS X1,
CASE [comments] WHEN 'FALSE' THEN 'FALSE' ELSE NULL END AS X2
FROM Table1;
```

**[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/158e3/3)**

Comment: ELSE NULL can be omitted for short.